# Android studio - MVP Pattern

Tags: android, android-studio, authentication, mvp, android-mvp

I'm using MVP design pattern in an android studio app. I have login and signup activities which both have some functions which are the same. Is there a way no to copy paste the same functions from one view to the other one?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using MVP, you can make that common function in your presenter and then use it for login and signup. Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Those functions are not a logic functions so they must be in the view. Those functions are functions the change the view.

Comment: So make a common function in the Activity outside of the onCreate method and then you can use it for both.